# How to properly insert time values in mysql using php framework laravel 5.1?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

Actually, I'm trying to insert some 'time' values in mysql database using laravel 5.1 eloquent. But I'm getting that ZERO time error.

I insert some time, like '06:55:00' and in the database shows '00:00:00'.

So, I want to understand the better practices to insert datetime values and avoid this kind of errors.

Here the actual code that I'm working on:

```
$some_var = ModelClass::create([
                           'time1' => date('H:m:s', strtotime('06:30:00')),
                           'time2' => date('H:m:s', strtotime('14:55:00'))
                          ])->pluck('id');
```

And I got this in the database:

```
id         |     time1     |      time2     |
 1         |   00:00:00    |    00:00:00    |
```

Comment: Have you tried using `Carbon`, Laravel's implementation of getting timestamps? I have never come across this error but I usually use `Carbon::now` method because it is more flexible. take a look and try it out, if it works then I will make this comment an answer http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-mutators#date-mutators

Comment: You also have to tell the model which fields are dates: `protected $dates = ['time1', 'time2'];`

Comment: I never used Carbon. I'll test it now, thanks!

Comment: Carbon is awesome. I made some changes in the model too. It worked!

Comment: Ops...sorry, @Barranka.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to **samlev**

Using Carbon solved my problem, and looks like a good way to work with DateTime values.

If anybody else is has problems with another kind of php framework, maybe could use it too.

just access [carbon's page here.](https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon)